# Smallest Square Function

Tags: python, function, recursion

Consider a positive integer n. What will be the smallest number k such that if we concatenate the digits of n with those of k we get a perfect square?

For example, for n=1 the smallest k is 6 since 16 is a perfect square.

For n=4, k has to be 9 because 49 is a perfect square.

For n=35, k is 344, since 35344=1882 is the smallest perfect square starting with the digits 35.

Define the smallestSquare function that takes a positive integer n and returns the smallest integer k whose concatenation of the digits of n,k results in a perfect square.

For now all I have is this, which checks wether the given number is a perfect square or not.
I would like to solve this using recursion but I'm not even sure where to start.

```
from math import sqrt

def isSquare(n):
  return n == int(sqrt(n) + 0.5) ** 2
  
def smallestSquare(n):
```

Comment: Are you looking for "the smallest perfect square starting with n" or the "smallest number k" such that conatenating n and k yields a perfect square? The two may not be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

No recursion is necessary:

```
def smallestSquare(n):
    x = 1
    while isSquare(int(str(n)+str(x))) == False:
        x += 1
    return int(str(n)+str(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

If, given some number 'n', you are looking for the smallest perfect suqare that begins with 'n', the following is an approach that should work:

```
import math

def find_smallest_perfect_square(start: int) -> int:
    while True:
        if int(math.sqrt(start)) != math.sqrt(start):
            start += 1
        else:
            return start
        
def find_concatenation(n: int) -> int:
    str_n = str(n)
    while True:
        val = find_smallest_perfect_square(n)
        if str(val).startswith(str_n):
            return val
        else:
            n = val + 1
```

Testing:

```
for i in range(10):
    print (f'The smallest perfect square that begins with {i} is {find_concatenation(i)}')

# Result:
    # The smallest perfect square that begins with 0 is 0
    # The smallest perfect square that begins with 1 is 1
    # The smallest perfect square that begins with 2 is 25
    # The smallest perfect square that begins with 3 is 36
    # The smallest perfect square that begins with 4 is 4
    # The smallest perfect square that begins with 5 is 529
    # The smallest perfect square that begins with 6 is 64
    # The smallest perfect square that begins with 7 is 729
    # The smallest perfect square that begins with 8 is 81
    # The smallest perfect square that begins with 9 is 9
```

If what you're looking for is "the smallest value of k" which, when concatenated with n, yields a perfect square - the above approach is not guaranteed to give you what you want. If that's what you require, please specify.